# Why can't I bind to 127.0.0.1 on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, bind

I'm trying to set up a simple web server on Mac OS X, and I keep getting an error when I run `bind`. Here's what I'm running (this transcript uses GNU Guile, but just as a convenient interface to posix).

```
(define addr (inet-aton "127.0.0.1"))                     ; get internal representation of 127.0.0.1
(define sockaddr (make-socket-address AF_INET addr 8080)) ; make a struct sockaddr
(define sock (socket PF_INET SOCK_STREAM 0))              ; make a socket
(bind sock sockaddr)                                      ; bind the socket to the address
```

That gives me the error `In procedure bind: can't assign requested address`.

So I tried it again allowing *any* address.

```
(define anyaddr (make-socket-address AF_INET INADDR_ANY 8080)) ; allow any address
(bind sock anyaddr)
```

And that works fine. But it's weird, because `ifconfig lo0` says

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
  inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
  inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
  inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
```

So the loopback device is assigned to `127.0.0.1`. So my question is, why can't I bind to that address?

Thanks.

Update: the output of `route get 127.0.0.1` is

```
   route to: localhost
destination: localhost
  interface: lo0
      flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,LOCAL>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
   49152     49152         0         0         0         0     16384         0
```

Comment: Is there something already listening on port 8080?  What does `netstat` say? e.g. `netstat -a -n -f inet | grep '127.0.0.1:8080'` or similar.

Comment: Mikel: that command produces no results. Running just `netstat -a -n -f inet` also produces nothing interesting: just some tcp connections to stackoverflow and a bunch of udp ports.

Comment: Oh, and running Guile with root privileges doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly an answer, since it doens't directly solve you problem...but it looks as if your problem is particular to guile.  That is, on my OS X
10.6 system, I have the same problem you do using the guile code from
you example.  On the other hand, the following works just fine:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
s.listen(5)

c, addr = s.accept()
c.send('hello\n')
c.close()
```

If I run this code, I can see the socket listening:

```
netstat -f inet -an | grep 8080
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.8080         *.*                    LISTEN
```

And connecting to port 8080 does what you would expect:

```
$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Yep, I just replicated your results. It must be a problem with Guile. I'll talk to the development list and track it down.

Comment: Did you ever track this down? I'm having almost exactly the same problem, except that it's a different Lisp dialect (TXR Lisp), and the protocol is IPV4 UDP. The OS is MacOS 10.7.3 (Lion).   I can bind a UDP socket to address 0, but not 127.0.0.1: can't assign requested address.   The code runs fine on the 32 and 64 bit x86 Linux port of the language, as well as Solaris 10.

Comment: @Kaz - You need to post a new question (and not as an edit to the original question).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Nonsense; it's almost certainly the same issue. I'm not about to post an exact duplicate question! Clearing the structure to all zero bytes before assigning the fields fixes it.

Comment: @Kaz Sorry but not nonsense. Your edit has already been rejected , as you posted your own question into someone else's. If it's the same question, then upvote the question. Otherwise... post a new question. No need to argue here anymore (where we're now overtaking someone's answer with this conversation).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Whatever; you and your posse do whatever you want; I solved it for myself and posted an answer. **The platform, API and symptoms are exactly the same (modulo minor version number of OS).** My edit to the question added a what is called a *data point* in empirical science.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, in my case, the problem is with the uninitialized fields in the structure which have nothing to do with the semantic socket address.

I added a `memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa)` and now it binds.

It is almost certainly the case that the Guile implementation was running into the same issue: initializing just the documented fields of `struct sockaddr_in`.  The symptoms were exactly the same, in any case: `INADDR_ANY` binding, yet `INADDR_LOOPBACK` refusing with the same `errno`.

Edit: sorry if I'm unclear; I'm referring to something I added to the question which someone removed. Namely, I ran into exactly the same problem in the implementation of (by sheer coincidence) another Lisp dialect. I added my observations, along with some `gdb` debug session traces showing the contents of the `struct sockaddr_in` before the `bind` call. The address showed correctly initialized `sin_family`, `sin_addr` and `sin_port` fields. However, the `sin_len` field at the head of the structure (present on Darwin, absent on other platforms) was uninitialized, as well as a `sin_zero` padding array at the end.